# How to filter multiple rows in dataview

Tags: asp.net, dataview, rowfilter

I need to filter multiple rows in dataview. Here I used rowfilter. But, I want to filter multiple rows. Which command can be used? My code is:

```
foreach (string s1 in list)  
{  
     if (s1 != string.Empty)
     {
         dvData.RowFilter = "(code like '" + searchText + "*') AND (code <> '" + s1 + "')";
     }
}
```

The problem is, it takes only one value and it is overwritten during the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add all *codes* for `code` field in `RowFilter` then you can try this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach(string s in list){
    if (s != string.Empty)
        sb.Append(string.Format(" AND (code <> '{0}')", s));
}

string rowFilter = string.Format("(code like '{0}*')", searchText) + sb.ToString();

dvData.RowFilter = rowFilter;
```

Comment: thanks , its working fine. instead of using 'in' in the command. here u appended with 'and' command.